# Add attribute to selected item using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a multiple selection ListBox that uses the chosen-jquery plugin.  I need to set the attribute property of the selected list items.

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen().change(function (evt) {
   var label = $(this.options[this.selectedIndex]).closest('optgroup').prop('label');
   alert(label);

   if (label == "Global Groups") {
      $(this.options[this.selectedIndex]).attr("grouping", "GlobalGroups");
   }
   else if (label == "Personal Groups") {
      $(this.options[this.selectedIndex]).attr("grouping", "PersonalGroups");
   }
   else {
      $(this.options[this.selectedIndex]).attr("grouping", "Individuals");
   }
});
```

The `label` will return the correct value the first time but not for subsequent selections.
I believe I only need to get the currently selected item to set the attribute.  Then in the code-behind I will use it to set values in different lists.

How do I set the currently selected item to set the attribute value?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lstBoxTo" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple"
                    data-placeholder="Choose recipient(s)…" multiple="true" class="chosen-select">
        </asp:ListBox>
```

**UPDATE**
This is the entire document.ready function:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        //Create groups for recipient dropdown list
        $(".chosen-select option[grouping='GlobalGroups']").wrapAll("<optgroup label='Global Groups'>");
        $(".chosen-select option[grouping='PersonalGroups']").wrapAll("<optgroup label='Personal Groups'>");
        $(".chosen-select option[grouping='Individuals']").wrapAll("<optgroup label='Individuals'>");

        //Configure the ListBox using the 'chosen' jquery plugin
        $(".chosen-select").chosen({
            search_contains: true,
            no_results_text: "Sorry, no match!",
            allow_single_deselect: true
        });
        $('.chosen-container').css('width', '600px');


        $(".chosen-select").chosen().change(function (evt) {
            var label = $(this.options[this.selectedIndex]).closest('optgroup').prop('label');
            alert(label);

            if (label == "Global Groups") {
                $(this.options[this.selectedIndex]).attr("grouping", "GlobalGroups");
            }
            else if (label == "Personal Groups") {
                $(this.options[this.selectedIndex]).attr("grouping", "PersonalGroups");
            }
            else {
                $(this.options[this.selectedIndex]).attr("grouping", "Individuals");
            }
        });
    });



 enter code here
```

Comment: did you really not google 'set jquery attribute' before posting this?

Comment: Show HTML, explain further but briefly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I need the attribute set for the ListItems that are selected.  I set them in the code-behind to create the option groups but they are lost when I try to get them in the code-behind on a button click event.  So I think if I set the attributes for the selected items, I can use them in the button click event.

Comment: The '.selectedIndex' is the current selected value.  It seems to show only the first.  So does it return all of the selected indices?  How do I get only the latest selected index?

Comment: Why was this question given a down vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work(not tested)

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen().change(function (evt) {
        $(".chosen-select").find("option:selected").each(function(){
                    var label = $(this).closest('optgroup').prop('label');
                    alert(label);

                    if (label == "Global Groups") {
                        $(this).attr("grouping", "GlobalGroups");
                    }
                    else if (label == "Personal Groups") {
                        $(this).attr("grouping", "PersonalGroups");
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).attr("grouping", "Individuals");
                    }
                });
        });
```

Comment: Thank you!  That worked like a charm.  So you have to go thru the whole list of selected items and set the attribute each time an item is selected.  I thought you could just set the latest selected item.  But this will do just fine.